# SQL server 2008: read data till end of data in row

Tags: java, sql-server

Is there any way to read data from sql table...which read only number of value required (from all coloumns) using java language

like example,

```
id     arg1       arg2        arg3
1      maxx      123          0
2      milan      345         1
```

This is our sql table and at a single time we need only arg1 and arg2 and othertime we need all the values than how can we fetch dynamically...........beacuse every time we need different number of values so simple select query is not usefull..............if anyone can help please.....thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean? You can easily decide how many values you want from the database. Whether it's "select * from table" or "select arg1, arg2 from table". This is basic SQL.

Comment: so, use sql queries like select args1, args2 from table where to get result containing only args1 and args2. Where is the problem?

Comment: @milan.s Did you mean you want to create a sql query dynamicly?

Comment: yes!! it is not fixed every time arguements will be different so i need to read arguement values as per requirment so i need to create a query dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bogdan M. wrote, some more code would have been more helpful. Based on your given information, here my idea from scratch:

```
int numberOfArg = 0;
numberOfArgs = ? //assign the number of arguments here

StringBuilder mySqlQuerySb = new StringBuilder();
mySqlQuerySb.append("Select ");  
for (int num = 0; num < numberOfArgs; num++)
{ 
    mySqlQuerySb.append("arg"+(num +1));
    if ((num +1) != numberOfArgs) {mySqlQuerySb.append(",");}
}
mySqlQuerySb.append(" from table");  
String mySqlQueryStr = mySqlQuerySb.toString();
```

Hopefully it will help to get -at least- a start.

Comment: What did you mean with "get null in the table"? My idea does just create a dynamic select query string

Answer (score 0):

I would personally add an nvarchar(max)`params`  where i pass the arguments, where I by default set for instance arg1,arg2,null,null,arg5

then in the procedure i iterate over the params, with a delimiter like `,` and i get  the ones different from null, and in a series of if clauses i decide, if 1,2,5 do this, if 3,4,5 do other.

Hope it helps. (not a best practice or a officially recommandet one) And yes it would be doable for an small number of columns.

Mention: some code would have helped you more in achieving your goal.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not the one i am looking for!! anyway thanks for co-operate and help